# How does getchar_unlocked() work?

Tags: c, char, getchar

My question is based on a CodeChef problem called [Lucky Four](http://www.codechef.com/problems/LUCKFOUR).

This is my code:

```
int count_four() {
  int count = 0;
  char c = getchar_unlocked();
  while (c < '0' || c > '9')
    c = getchar_unlocked();
  while (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
    if (c == '4')
      ++count;
    c = getchar_unlocked();
  }
  return count;
}

int main() {
  int i, tc;
  scanf("%d", &tc);
  for (i = 0; i < tc; ++i) {
    printf("%d\n", count_four());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Let's say I make a slight change to `count_four()`:

```
int count_four() {
  int count = 0;
  char c = getchar_unlocked();
  while (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
    if (c == '4')
      ++count;
    c = getchar_unlocked();
  }
  while (c < '0' || c > '9') // I moved this `while` loop
    c = getchar_unlocked();
  return count;
}
```

This is my output after moving the `while` loop below the other one:

```
0
3
0
1
0
```

instead of:

```
4
0
1
1
0
```

The input used to test the program:

```
5
447474
228
6664
40
81
```

Why is this happening? How do `getchar()` and `getchar_unlocked()` work?

Comment: What's your sample input?

Comment: @RSahu 
Its given in the question itself follow the link
any way its Input:
5
447474
228
6664
40
81

Comment: It is better to put the sample input here rather than expecting others to follow the link to find it out.

Comment: Sample 
Input:
5
447474
228
6664
40
81

Output:
4
0
1
1
0

Comment: It works fine at http://ideone.com/jy8BwY after changing `getchar_unlocked` to just `getchar`. I don't know whether that is significant.

Answer (score 1):

`getchar_unlocked` is just a lower level function to read a byte from the stream without locking it.  In a single thread program, it behaves exactly like `getchar()`.

Your change in the `count_four` function changes its behavior completely.

The original function reads the standard input.  It skips non digits, causing an infinite loop at end of file.  It then counts digits until it gets a `'4'`. The count is returned.

Your version reads the input, it skips digits, counting occurrences of `'4'`, it then skips non digits, with the same bug on EOF, and finally returns the count.